# CodeIgniter Image Manipulation Class: How to make thumb_marker in the beginning of file name?

Tags: codeigniter

I use CodeIgniter Image Manipulation Class to make a Thumbnail of my images.

so the problem is: the property thumb_marker job is inserting '_thumb' just before the file extension, so mypic.jpg would become mypic_thumb.jpg

but what I want is the opposite I need my file name be: thumb_mypic.jpg

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extend the Image library.

```
class My_Image_lib extends Image_lib {

    public function initialize() {
        // copy the initialize method content here.
    }
}
```

Now, look for this line in initialize():

```
$this->full_dst_path = $this->dest_folder.$filename.$this->thumb_marker.$file_ext;
```

Change it to. Notice the `$this->thumb_marker` and `$filename` change:

```
$this->full_dst_path = $this->dest_folder.$this->thumb_marker.$filename.$file_ext;
```

Last you should set `My_Image_lib->thumb_marker = 'thumb_';`

Answer (score 0):

Edit this file
\system\libraries\Image_lib.php

replace (~line 595)

```
$this->full_dst_path = $this->dest_folder.$filename.$this->thumb_marker.$file_ext;
on
$this->full_dst_path = $this->dest_folder.$this->thumb_marker.$filename.$file_ext;
```