# Add custom name (not thumbnail to the beginning) of image file while uploading it in codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am learning the work with image manipulation in codeigniter3. Here is the code that adds thumb at the end of file

```
$config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
```

I wonder, if I have an image codeigniter.jpg, after manipulation it will be codeigniter_thumb.jpg, how can I add some chars to filename? For example: 84x84codeigniter_thumb.jpg or 84x84anotherfilename_thumb.jpg and etc.

Comment: Extend the Image library. Please look [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569748/codeigniter-image-manipulation-class-how-to-make-thumb-marker-in-the-beginning) answer

Comment: Possible duplicate of [CodeIgniter Image Manipulation Class: How to make thumb\_marker in the beginning of file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569748/codeigniter-image-manipulation-class-how-to-make-thumb-marker-in-the-beginning)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunatelly it is hard-coded, but you can rename file right after upload

```
if ($this->upload->do_upload()){           
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    $thumbnail = $data['raw_name'].'_thumb'.$data['file_ext']; // Here is the file name to rename
}
```

OR override class method as proposed in this answer: [CodeIgniter Image Manipulation Class: How to make thumb_marker in the beginning of file name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4569748/codeigniter-image-manipulation-class-how-to-make-thumb-marker-in-the-beginning)

Comment: I do not want thumb at the beginning, I want my own chars at the beginning, then the filename

Comment: Then you need to override class and use it instead of built-in one. That's an expected action in OOP